# Post file to SharePoint from Salesforce

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, sharepoint

I am trying to upload a file from SFDC Apex code to SharePoint

```
        HttpRequest httpRequestToSend = new HttpRequest();
        httpRequestToSend.setEndpoint('https://mysharepointsite.sharepoint.com/sites/testing/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\''+'/sites/testing/Shared%20Documents/Test'+'\')/files/add(url=\''+'document3.txt'+'\', overwrite=true)');
        httpRequestToSend.setMethod('POST');
        httpRequestToSend.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
        httpRequestToSend.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json;odata=verbose');
        httpRequestToSend.setBody('test message');
        
        System.debug('***** httpRequestToSend-->' + httpRequestToSend);
        System.debug('***** httpRequestToSend.getBody-->' + httpRequestToSend.getBody());
        
        Http http = new Http();   
        HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequestToSend);  
        System.debug('***** httpResponse-->' + httpResponse.getBody());
```

But I keep getting the following error:

HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.

I tried the following suggestion with the post below and the other forums out there but I can't figure out how to fix this.

[Sharepoint Integration From Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/250293/sharepoint-integration-from-apex)

Comment: I believe you'll need to convert the body that you are sending into a Blob. The linked example has this line ```httpRequestToSend.setBodyAsBlob(Blob.ValueOf('test Message'));``` rather than just setting the body as a string.